# Wondering about Cambridge definition of "absenteeism"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Cambridge Dictionary says here :](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/absenteeism)

- The high levels of absenteeism at the company were caused by poor management.

I wondering, cause of "measurement" 
The definition : "high levels of absenteeism". If I understand "absenteeism" as noun. " other variant " The high level of absenteeism " Why did Cambridge use " levels (plural) instead of "high level of absenteeism" (singular) ?

Comment: Let us suppose that there are 30 working accounts to deal or communicate with, does Cambridge defines that "state" of Data in separately personnel relation. So to choose "levels-plural" is fine.
There is a sentence in my mind" The level of absence" or "the level of absenteeism´s (plural) .

Comment: The company might measure absenteeism for various categories of employees. That's why. It could also be singular if the overall level of absent employees is measured.

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, "overall level" was the expression i was also thinking of.

Comment: I found another Cambridge excerpt:  " She has had repeated absences from work this year.  (more personal)

Comment: That's right. Absences for  people are countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually **high levels of {something}** implies multiple assays or surveys of the level, hence the plural.

But because that is how the words are normally found, we find some native speakers using those very same words in situations where there is nothing to justify the plural, **levels**:

> High levels of mercury were found in his blood.